# Implement JBoss WS-Security Username Token Profile authentication

Tags: authentication, jboss, web-services, ws-security

1. I implemented a web service with JAX-WS, and my service client is implemented with JAX-WS too, and the client can talk to service with WS-Security username token profile authentication.
2. Now I want to deploy this service to JBoss 4.2.3 and want to replace the custom authentication with Java EE container authentication.
3. I read some documents on JBossWS, and did some configuration by changing/adding web.xml, jboss-web.xml, jboss-wsse-server.xml, login-config.xml. But JBoss always sent 401 response to the client (the client SOAP request contained correct username token profile header in it).

Any help is appreciated.

1. Is that possible to implement such requirement via JBoss configuration?
2. Or show me a simple example/steps for configuring JBoss for authentication with WSSE username token profile.
3. Or how can I debug what's the problem with my current JBoss configuration.

Comment: You can start by replacing "changing/adding web.xml, jboss-web.xml, jboss-wsse-server.xml, login-config.xml." with what exactly you have added/changed. Post your configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question, here's a step-by-step tutorial available:

http://community.jboss.org/message/338347